# Issue iterating through an array of hashes and actually changing the values of the hashes in the original array

Tags: perl

So, I have an array of hashes, @doc_vector.  I want to go through each hash and modify the values of the keys.

The original code that I was working with is as follows:

```
my %hash=undef;

foreach my $hash (@doc_vector) {
      foreach my $key (keys %{ $hash }) {
         $hash{ $key } = log($dnum/$dfreq_hash{$key});
     }
 }
```

But, when I actually referred to the hashes in @doc_vector, the values were never modified.
I was able to modify a particular value by doing the following (I saved the index of the last hash entry and a key whose value I knew, $last_doc and $word, respectively):

```
foreach my $hash (@doc_vector) {
      foreach my $key (keys %{ $hash }) {
            if ($key eq $word)
         {
             $doc_vector[$last_doc]{$word}=log($dnum/$dfreq_hash{$key});                        
         }
       }
     }
```

That worked fine, but when I tried to do this for all of my entries:

```
foreach my $hash (@doc_vector) {
      foreach my $key (keys %{ $hash }) {
         $doc_vector[$hash]{$key}=log($dnum/$dfreq_hash{$key});
     }
     print "I'm going infinite\n";
 }
```

I end up printing "I'm going infinite" over and over again.  I have a feeling that the issue is that I'm putting in a hash reference, $hash, instead of an index, but I don't know how to get the index (and the way that I originally tried to do this (1st code segment didn't work).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the `%hash`?  If strict/warnings required it, it's an indication of the problems further down the code...

Comment: `my %hash = undef;` doesn't do what you think it does. It is equivalent to `my %hash = ( '' => undef );`. Except that the first form will produce warnings with `use warnings;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to store values in an existing hash, creating a new hash (with `my %hash`) is not the way to go.

The reason Perl was giving you an error before you hid it with `my %hash` is because you're accessing a hash named `%hash` instead of the hash referenced by `$hash`.

To access elements of a hash via a reference, you can use

```
$hash->{$key}
```

so your code should be

```
foreach my $hash (@doc_vector) {
   foreach my $key (keys %{ $hash }) {
      $hash->{$key} = log($dnum/$dfreq_hash{$key});
   }
}
```

Documentation on references:

- [Mini-Tutorial: Dereferencing Syntax](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=977408)
- [References quick reference](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=69927)
- [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)
- [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)
- [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)
- [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html)

Answer (score 1):

`$hash{$key}` refers to an element of the hash variable `%hash`, which is a completely different variable than the hash reference `$hash`.

To access the element of a hash reference, use the dereference operator `->`

```
$hash->{$key} = log($dnum/$dfreq_hash{$key});
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?  I think that you should not have introduced the `my %hash = undef;` as Perl was trying to tell you about some problems.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @doc_vector = ( { key1 => 12, key2 => 14 }, { key3 => 17, key4 => 23 } );

sub dump_doc
{
    my($tag, @doc) = @_;
    print "$tag:\n";
    foreach my $hash (@doc)
    {
        foreach my $key (keys %{$hash})
        {
            print "$key: $hash->{$key}\n";
        }
    }
}

dump_doc("Before", @doc_vector);

print "Fixing:\n";
foreach my $hash (@doc_vector)
{
    foreach my $key (keys %{$hash})
    {
        print "$key: $hash->{$key}\n";
        $hash->{$key} = log($hash->{$key});
    }
}

dump_doc("After", @doc_vector);
```

Output:

```
Before:
key2: 14
key1: 12
key4: 23
key3: 17
Fixing:
key2: 14
key1: 12
key4: 23
key3: 17
After:
key2: 2.63905732961526
key1: 2.484906649788
key4: 3.13549421592915
key3: 2.83321334405622
```